# Which timezone are the platform events run with?

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, timezone, platform-event

What does Salesforce use as the system time when running those jobs? The current system time (UTC)?

My context is that I have a job that is run every 30 minutes and it executes a task for some of my users. The User object has 4 numeric fields to represent start hour, end hour, start minute and end minute. With those fields I calculate the second in the day the job should start, and the second it should end. With those two values I can compare with the system's current second, and check if the job should run for the user or not.

Some days ago this was a scheduled class that was rescheduling itself using my user credentials ('Scheduled by Renato' and records would be marked as 'Last modified by Renato' too). Then I decided to change to platform events so they would be marked as "Last modified by Automated Process" instead (which is what I want).

Now everytime the class is run, it publishes a event, and the event trigger fires the class' code that was inside the `execute` block. However, the timing seems off, and users are not receiving the tasks in the correct time anymore.

To get the current second correctly, I've used this code:

```
Integer offset = TimeZone.getTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo').getOffSet(DateTime.now());
Integer current_second = Util.getCurrentSecond() + (offset/1000);
```

Util class' method:

```
public static Integer getCurrentSecond() {
    return Integer.valueOf((DateTime.now().hour() * 60 * 60) + (DateTime.now().minute() * 60));
}
```

Have I not considered something when using the Platform Events?

**Edit:**

I just edited my code to include a call to a service that sends a message to me through Telegram. The code ran in the platform event context, and the timing is correct. System time is UTC and São Paulo is UTC-2 (originally -3, but -2 because of Daylight Saving Time):

```
System second: 21960
Current second: 14760
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a while and after some debugging I managed to get the system to print its timezone using `UserInfo.getTimeZone()`. **Salesforce server runs in the Pacific Standard Time (PST) timezone.**

Now for the issue I was having: apparently there's a bug with the `DateTime.now().hour()` call. When I ran it at 11 AM (GMT-2) the system would print the DateTime as expected, as `13:00:00`. However, when using `.hour()` Apex would return me `5` instead of `13`. This caused a miscalculation in my code.

I've then fixed this temporarily with the following code:

```
Integer offset = TimeZone.getTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo').getOffSet(DateTime.now());
String ds = DateTime.now()+''; // datetime string
Integer hour = Integer.valueOf(ds.split(' ')[1].split(':')[0]) + (offset/1000/60/60);
```

And `.minute()` and `.second()` are working just fine, by the way.