# What time zone is used for platform events?

Tags: timezone, platform-event

When code is run in the context of a platform event, which time zone is chosen as the context time zone, and can that time zone be configured?

Unlike site guest users, the "Process Automated" entity doesn't seem to have related user record where a time zone can be set.

Comment: same as [Which timezone are the platform events run with?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/202019/which-timezone-are-the-platform-events-run-with) , no answer though. and there is no mention of this in the platform events [documentation](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/210/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/platform_events.pdf)

Comment: @glls Good find.